# How to retrive data from flattened structure

Tags: javascript, firebase

Here's my data:

```
{
    "users": {
        "someRandomUserId": {
            "name": "Name 1",
            "accounts": {
                "someRandomAccountId": true
            }
        },
        "someRandomUserId2": {
            "name": "Name 2",
            "accounts": {
                "someRandomAccountId": true,
                "someRandomAccountId2": true
            }
        }
    },
    "accounts": {
        "someRandomAccountId": {
            "name": "Account1",
            "users": {
                "someRandomUserId": true,
                "someRandomUserId2": true
            }
        },
        "someRandomAccountId2": {
            "name": "Account2",
            "users": {
                "someRandomUserId2": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After reading through the docs I believe this is how I should have it set up. If I'm completely in left field here please let me know. My actual question is given that I have the user id of 'someRandomUserId2' how do I get a list of accounts that the user is associated with along with their data? I'd like to somehow get this data back:

```
"accounts": {
    "someRandomAccountId": {
        "name": "Account1"
    },
    "someRandomAccountId2": {
        "name": "Account2"
    }
}
```

Or at least something similar. I've tried to use startAt and endAt but I can't figure out how to get them to work on an object:

```
accountRef
    .orderByChild('users.' + userId)        
    .equalTo(true)
```

**UPDATE**

Here's my current method, which seems like overkill:

```
var userRef = myDataRef.child('users');
var accountRef = myDataRef.child('accounts');

var accounts = {};

var userAccounts = userRef.child(userId + '/accounts');

userAccounts.on('child_added', function(dataSnap){  
    var accountId = dataSnap.key();

    var accountData = accountRef.orderByKey().equalTo(accountId);

    accountData.on('child_added', function(dataSnap){
        accounts[accountId] = dataSnap.val();
    });
    accountData.on('child_removed', function(){
        delete accounts[accountId];
    });
});
userAccounts.on('child_removed', function(dataSnap){
    var accountId = dataSnap.key();
    delete accounts[accountId];
});
```

Comment: You can read the value at `users/someRandomUserId2/accounts` and based on that read the values at `accounts/someRandomAccountId` and `accounts/someRandomAccountId2`. If you're looking for a way to have Firebase do this 'cross-reference' automatically; there isn't one (yet?).

Comment: Yeah, the thing I'm trying to avoid is looping through all the accounts. Is that the only way to do it?

Comment: @Marein i've edited the question along with my initial attempt.

Comment: Not all the accounts, you only need to retrieve the relevant accounts. But yes, as far as I know, that is the only way right now.

Comment: Actually there might be one more way, let me try and write it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an additional structure to your database that specifically lists which users are part of which accounts, like this:

```
"accountusers": {
    "someRandomAccountId": {
        "someRandomUserId": true,
        "someRandomUserId2": true
    },
    "someRandomAccountId2": {
        "someRandomUserId2": true
    }
}
```

You could then use the following query to get all accounts belonging to `someRandomUserId2`:

```
ref.child("accountusers").orderByChild("someRandomUserId2").equalTo(true)
```

This method requires that the whole of `accountusers` is readable by the user.

`orderByChild` and `equalTo` only work one level deep. Otherwise, it would be possible to write a similar query for your existing datastructure.

Comment: Yeah, how does this return the account data? It's just the ids right? I really appreciate the answer though!

Comment: True, you'd then have to retrieve those from the database again. You need to do a retrieve-loop either way, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: I'll accept the answer because it seems that is the current way to do it. I've looked into Firebase.util and it does what I need it too really easily, just not sure how it'll handle security later on. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I hope Firebase will implement some functionality to make these kinds of things easier.